# Change QTextEdit's line-breaking algorithm?

Tags: qt, qtextedit

I want to change QTextEdit's line-breaking algorithm so that text I'm displaying that is not English (it's code, in fact) gets wrapped in a better way.  The definition of what a "word" is in Qt may be well-suited for human languages, but it is not well-suited for code, and so long lines of code end up getting wrapped at really bad places.  For example, this single line of code:

```
– (void)setRecombinationRate(numeric rates, [Ni ends = NULL], [string$ sex = "*"])
```

gets wrapped by QTextEdit, in a narrow window, to this:

```
–
 (void)setRecombinationRate(numeri
c rates, [Ni ends = NULL], [string
$ sex = "*"])
```

I would like to tailor the line-breaking algorithm to achieve something more like this:

```
– (void)setRecombinationRate(
numeric rates, [Ni ends = NULL], 
[string$ sex = "*"])
```

I have done much the same thing in Cocoa with an override of `-lineBreakBeforeIndex:withinRange:` in a subclass of `NSTextStorage`; what I'm wondering is whether there is a similar place for me to override the default behavior in Qt.

Note that I know you can customize Qt's layout so that text flows around obstacles within the `QTextEdit`; that is *not* what I'm asking about.

Comment: Well you can of course `QTextEdit::setWordWrapMode(QTextOption::WordWrap)` to avoid wrapping in middle of word. But I don't see a simple way to prefer wrapping at, say, `(`. I think you're looking at a custom [QAbstractTextDocumentLayout](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstracttextdocumentlayout.html) or something similar. QtCreator for example breaks like a QTextEdit (with WordWrap mode).  But I see SublimeText will break after the "(" in "Rate(numeric", before wrapping on the space after leading "-", which is nice.

Comment: FWIW, I traced the default wrapping to [here](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/gui/text/qtextlayout.cpp.html#_ZN9QTextLine13layout_helperEi). Not exactly something I'd want to reproduce. Hopefully there's a simpler way to set "preferred wrap characters" but I couldn't find it.

Comment: `QTextEdit::setWordWrapMode(QTextOption::WordWrap)` didn't end up being an improvement for my application; it allows the text to be wider than the view to avoid ever breaking a word (adding a horizontal scroller), which is not what I want, so I'm sticking with the default of `QTextOption::WrapAtWordBoundaryOrAnywhere`.  Wow, yes, that code you linked to is hardcore, and that method, `layout_helper()`, is private anyway.  Oh well.  Thanks for the research.  Looks like this is pretty much impossible to do within Qt right now.